# facebook like button blocked by company proxy

Tags: css

Hi i got a working facebook like button. However, facebook is blocked by my company thus my facebook button has been replace with a big company logo saying this is blocked.

How could i resolve this and give more confident to my user? I thought of this
1) When it detect the object is blocked by proxy, then hide the object(facebook button).
2) Reduce the size of the blocked image which has replaced the facebook like button.

Could you advice?

Comment: This seems silly. If Facebook is blocked, then users in your company should be used to seeing other websites broken in the same way.

Comment: Yes exactly. But could it be hidden if it is blocked?

Comment: Ask your network admin to give you access to facebook!! ;)

Comment: Ask the network engineer to give the developers the rights they need to do there jobs. If this is a requirement for the website that will be use externally there should be no problem. If this site will be used internally then you should reconsider the requirement vs network policy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach that I suggested to someone recently having the same issue. If Facebook is blocked, the 'like' button serves no purpose on the page. You can't see how many likes and you can't interact with it, so why display it at all?

This little piece of Javascript detects whether Facebook is blocked by attempting to load an image from Facebook's servers. If the image cannot be loaded, we add a class to the body tag which hides the iframe.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iguhu5

Try editing the URL by adding in a character, thus creating a 404, and see the iframe disappear.

Also, you could easily adapt this method to perform a slightly different task - displaying a message, for example.

Oh, and to be completely thorough, I should mention that there is one small caveat. If your company blocks 'facebook.com', but not its asset/CDN servers then you could potentially see the iframe even though Facebook would be blocked.

Answer (score 5):

Why not have a copy of the "Like" image on your server, then it will appear and it will all look fine on your website. If they try and like it, they will get a message saying that Facebook is blocked.

You can't detect if a proxy server is replacing content on your web page as it happens after you have served the page and different solutions use subtly different techniques to replace the content which makes client-side detection difficult.